# How to format time with different formats as hh:mm:ss in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in excel that outputs the time in different formats.

For example:

```
09:00:00
06:34 (excel thinks this means hh:mm, when it should be mm:ss)
:00
:01
```

I want to format the data as such:

```
09:00:00
00:06:34
00:00:00
00:00:01
```

How can I go about getting to this point? I need it as a formula in excel ideally, as new data is regularly pasted into the sheet.

Comment: You need to import the input data as text, otherwise, there is no way to distinguish the first case (row) from the second, once excel converts it to a number (time), there is no way to identify each scenario.

Comment: This is where a tool like Power Query really pays off.  It allows you to run a script against the data *before* it is presented to Excel for consumption.  The logic that determines whether a field should be interpreted as hours, minutes, or seconds would be in Power Query, and it would be converted into a consistent format that excel correctly interprets.  To David's point, once the data is imported into Excel, the data typing may already be done before you can do anything about it.